# Best practice for storing images to use on short term

Tags: android, memory-leaks

So, I'm using custom number tiles for images. The images are stored as resources. I've been tracing a memory leak, and have cause to believe the method I am storing these images for use is suspect. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
private void loadImageList()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"Reloading List "+imageList);
    if (imageList==null || imageList.size()<10)
    {
        imageList=new ArrayList<Bitmap>(10);
        imageList.add(0,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number0));
        imageList.add(1,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number1));
        imageList.add(2,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number2));
        imageList.add(3,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number3));
        imageList.add(4,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number4));
        imageList.add(5,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number5));
        imageList.add(6,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number6));
        imageList.add(7,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number7));
        imageList.add(8,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number8));
        imageList.add(9,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ant_number9));
    }
}

public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    loadImageList();

}
```

What will happen is if I open and close this application repeatedly, then the system won't have enough memory to add an image to the `ImageList`. I'm setting the image of the button like this (But with an object ImageButton, of course). I should add that the application is threaded, and this call resides in a `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`

```
ImageButton.setImageBitmap(imageList.get(current_var));
```

I've tried deleting the images in the `onStop()` command, but it will sometimes cause a crash when the thread tries to allocate the image stored in memory to the button, due to the threaded nature of the beast.

So, is there a better way that I can load these images that won't cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized something after posting this. I could just make the imageList static. These images aren't going to change from one view to the next. The Bitmaps don't contain a view, so the memory won't lock up. I'm already checking to see if the values exist before I'm using them. And this function is used so frequently that holding on to static memory won't hurt other aspects of the program. Sometimes it just helps to put it into words..